# How to create inner view dynamic in Xib Cell of tableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I have created custom Cell Xib for tableView and its working fine dynamically. If I set `numberofRowsInSection` return 2 count it will display two cells within tableView.
Actually I want to achieve list should append within same cell kind of tree view. screen shot attached.

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, URLSessionDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let urlList = [
    ["The Swift Programming Language", "https://swift.org/documentation/"],
    ["Crossdomain.xml", "https://crossdomain.xml"]]

    var downloadTaskList: [DownloadTaskInfo]?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "DownloadEntryViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DownloadEntryViewCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return urlList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadEntryViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadEntryViewCell        
        cell.footerLbl1.text = urlList[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.footerPrg1.progress = 0.0
        return cell
    }

}
```

Xib Code:

```
class DownloadEntryViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var rightView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftView: UIView!


    @IBOutlet weak var fileNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var downloadURLLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var individualProgress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!



    @IBOutlet weak var footerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var h1View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var v1View: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var footerLbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var footerProgressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var footerPrg1: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PinView1: UIView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

}
```

Comment: you can add stack view inside your cell then add subview in a stack.

Comment: have you tried adding tableview inside the cell, it should definitely work ?

Comment: @RuchiMakadia Can you just give me example for this little?

Comment: @SanadBarjawi No I haven't tried that. How can I use that ?

Comment: simply inside the cell instantiate  the tableiview and assign the delegate and the data source to the cell and return the actual data to the datasource funcs, etc..

Comment: replace var stackHeight = 0 to  var stackHeight:CGFloat = 0.0 and stackHeight = stackHeight + Int(33.0) to stackHeight = stackHeight + 33.0

Comment: @RuchiMakadia Yes I have done.  After that `cell.stackviewOption.addArrangedSubview(child_view)` Fatal nil error. Please check my code what mistakes I am doing.

Comment: yaa i just checked that coz you did totally wrong lemme correct all

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate.

Comment: check that working fine please upvote answer. here is link https://github.com/RuchiMakadia/DemoTeste.

Comment: perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your xib cell add vertical stackView.
now create custom UiView in another .xib file for your footer list.

in tableview `cellForRowAt`  method do like below

```
var stackHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
    for i in 1...ChildView.count
    {
        let child_view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ChildView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ChildView
        child_view.lblProgress.text = "Swift_programimg"
        cell.stackviewOption.addArrangedSubview(child_view)
         stackHeight = stackHeight + 60.0
    }
    cell.stackviewOption.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackHeight).isActive = true
```

here `ChildView` is footerview .xib and `stackviewOption` is vertical stackview.
for loop for how many you want fotter.

here line `cell.stackviewOption.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackHeight).isActive = true for set stackview height.`

line `stackHeight = stackHeight + 33.0` for add everytime childview height in total height of stackview.

Do the same logic for cell that should work.

Comment: Thank you let me implement that and get back to you.

Comment: I have implemented that getting two errors on `count` and `constraint` Can I share my code over the GitHub ?

Comment: the count is for an array of your childview.. i mean swiftprogramming and cross-platform text's array

Comment: count error I have set it giving URL counts. 
constraint error: `Cannot invoke 'constraint' with an argument list of type '(equalToConstant: Int)' `

Comment: Pardon me again bothering. Can I ask one question because its relevant to your code which you have shared?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have set model in the same code instead of `urlList` but its duplicating cells instead of footer row. 
Secondly how can I set space between main Row(xib) not footer one.  I have the same code link https://github.com/MasamMahmood/TestDownload

Comment: might be you not set correct that's why duplicating cell issue occur. for space between to cell, you can apply extra height in stackHeight after over for loop.

Comment: I exactly follow the same way of code. In my code I created JSON file and model. Please check the same link code above I have shared. Many thanks.

Comment: first thing you set dic?.projectName it's wrong set like "i.projectName" and the second thing you set  "return Appdata?.count ?? 0" in numberOfRowsInSection that's why it's duplicate cell.

Comment: Right I have set `i.projectName `now corrected. for numberofRowsInSection what I need to set instead of `Appdata?.count ?? 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `tableview` height  in  `heightforrowAt` to  `UITableView.automaticDimension` .

Make your top view inside `UIView` (lets call it view1) . Set its height to 0 with priority to 750 , now child inside `view1` will give the height to `view1`. Make outlet of bottom constraint of last child inside `view1` .

Disabling of bottom constraints will help you in hiding `view1` since we are first setting height to 0 and expecting child items to provide height . When we are disabling bottom constraint , child items will not able to provide . Hence `view1` will collapse to define height 0 .

Now for every `cellforrowatIndexpath` method call pass some parameters to hide or show top view .

```
func configureUI(cellData:String? , showTopView:Bool){
    mBtmCnst.isActive = showTopView
}
```

Make sure to mark top view  `view1` to `cliptobounds` true and  mBtmCnst to `strong` outlet .

Hope this helps you!